# node-webkit: doesn't show active content?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nw.js, jquery-reel

I have a small nw.js app that alters the div section of the index.html page:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("outputSection");
var myImg = document.createElement("img");
myDiv.appendChild(myImg);

myImg.src = 'http://127.0.0.2:8080/prime_almost_full_00007.0001.png';
myImg.width = '256';
myImg.height = '256';
myImg.class = 'reel';
myImg.id = 'image';
myImg.setAttribute("data-images", 'http://127.0.0.2:8080/prime_almost_full_00007.####.png|0001..0250');
```

The HTML code I'm trying to mimic in my static example, which works, is:

```
<img src='http://127.0.0.2:8080/prime_almost_full_00007.0001.png'width='256' height='256' class='reel' id='image' data-images='http://127.0.0.2:8080/prime_almost_full_00007.####.png|0001..0021'>
```

I'm using the Jquery-reels library. At the top of my page, I include it thusly:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://code.vostrel.cz/jquery.reel.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

For some reason, while the image shows up with the first code snipped, it isn't interactive. My static page, which works is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://code.vostrel.cz/jquery.reel.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<head>
  <title>Hi there</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <img src='http://127.0.0.2:8080/prime_almost_full_00007.0001.png' 
         width='256' 
         height='256' 
         class='reel' 
         id='image' 
         data-images='http://127.0.0.2:8080/prime_almost_full_00007.####.png|0001..0021'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's not clear to me why this is happening. Is it something about node-webkit?

EDIT: re-scanning doesn't seem to work:

```
myDiv.innerHTML = "<img src='http://127.0.0.2:8080/prime_almost_full_00007.0001.png' width='256' height='256' class='reel' id='image' data-images='http://127.0.0.2:8080/prime_almost_full_00007.####.png|0001..0021'>";
$.reel.scan();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page loads, the reel plugin automatically looks for elements with the attribute class="reel". See [the annotated source](http://test.vostrel.net/jquery.reel/docs/jquery.reel.html#Quick-Start) for more info about this.

According to that documentation, since you are adding an element to the page after the page loads, you may need to call the $.reel.scan() function at the end of your javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your response, that doesn't work though. I wonder if there's other re-scanning methods.

Comment: This is the right answer. Something else was mucking my content up.